# Adding Narrowband Interference to Spread Spectrum Signal in MATLAB (Baseband Model)

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, spread-spectrum, baseband, cdma

I am interested in adding a narrowband interfering signal to my spread spectrum signal.

In the waveform model, it's straightforward to generate a narrowband signal within the frequency range of the spread spectrum. However, I'm unsure about how to add a narrowband interfering signal to a spread spectrum signal in a baseband model using MATLAB. Could anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Generate the usual -fs/2 to fs/2 noise, then bandpass-filter it.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. However, for the bandpass filter again I would need frequency. In my case, I am using a baseband model and simulating the system without specifying the frequency.

Comment: Then, how do you define "narrowband"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single tone interferor at baseband is given as $e^{j\omega_c t}$ where $\omega_c$ is the radian frequency within the signal's bandwidth.

For example, if we had a spread spectrum signal with bandwidth of 10 MHz centered on a 1 GHz carrier, and we had a single-tone jammer at 1.001 GHz (1 MHz higher than the carrier frequency), then at baseband where the same spread spectrum waveform would be centered on DC (and extending +/-5 MHz), we would create the jammer using $Ke^{j2\pi (1e6) t}$, where $K$ is a real scaling constant.

What may not be clear and leading to the question is that the waveform in the passband is identical to the waveform at complex baseband other than the carrier changing from a real sinusoid to DC. Since a real waveform must have a complex conjugate symmetric spectrum (the negative frequency spectrum is identical to the positive frequency spectrum with opposite phase), then the baseband waveform must be complex in order to have an independent spectrum on each side of the carrier (such as our example of a single tone jammer offset from the carrier). This is demonstrated in the graphic below showing how we frequency translate a waveform from an RF carrier to complex baseband.

[image: IQ downconverter]

Note too from Euler's formula that a real sinusoid is made up of two individual tones in the Fourier spectrum; one at a positive frequency as $e^{j\omega t}$ and the other at a negative frequency as $e^{-j\omega t}$:

$$\cos(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{j\omega t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-j\omega t}$$